# iMac 27” Mid-2010 GPU upgrade

Tags: imac, gpu, hardware-recommendation

I am using an iMac 27“ 2010 and I like to upgrade the Graphics Card. I know the Radeon 6970 from the later 2011 iMac will do the trick, but it would only be a slightly upgrade in performance.

Does someone have any further info which MXM GPU is the latest and will still work with the Mac described above?

thx

Comment: I have the same question. I just installed Mojave on my 2010 iMac with using dosdude1 patch. It works, but with weird colors and without graphic acceleration, so it's not usable. The patch says I need to upgrade my Graphic card because Radeon HD 5xxx/6xxx series are not supported on Mojave/Catalina

Comment: Maybe this tread will help you out: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/2011-imac-graphics-card-upgrade.1596614/page-273

Comment: The linked dupe references the 2009, but the GPUs from 2009 -2011 are interchangeable.